# Valums Ajax Upload: Canceling a file saved in the input

Tags: ajax, uploading

I need to be able to cancel the file that is saved in the hidden iframe file input.  The problem is if you select a file and try to upload and get an error (for instance if you haven't filled out all the information in the form yet) if you try to upload the same file again it just doesn't work, the onSubmit won't fire ever.

I added a custom cancel function to the AjaxUpload object.  I am aware they have updated their script to a new version however what we have works fine and when I took a look at their new stuff it is completely changed in the state of how it works and what it offers.  The function is as followed:

```
        cancel: function () {
            this._clearInput();
            this.iframe.src = "javascript:'<html></html>';";
        },
```

This should have done the trick however it is not working as desired.  Calling myUploader.cancel() isn't erroring and it's not working.

I just need a simple hack or work around to get this to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround by using jquery to search for the input and clear it out.

$('input[type=file]').val('');

for those that have the same issue.